# List information aggregation

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I have the following scenario:

```
class Task {
    int id;
    Group group;
    User user;
    boolean successful;
}
```

User is part of Group, and Group-User relationship is many-to-many (user may belong to multiple groups and a group may contain multiple users). Task is specific to a User in a Group.

There is a `List<Task>` for which I need to summarize the number of successful tasks per User in a Group and send update to the user. So, if a user belongs to several groups I need to update him **once for each group he belongs to** (with the number of successful tasks the user had **for that group**).

What would be the best way to achieve that? Our current algorithm is:

```
First, sort the list by Group ID and then by User ID.
Then: 

int successfulTasks = 0;
Group curGroup = null;
User curUser = null;
for(Task task : tasksByGroupAndUser) {
    if((task.getGroup() != curGroup) || (task.getUser() != curUser) {
        // Going to next user or group, update the previous user
        updateUser(user,group, successfulTasks);
        successfulTasks = 0;        
    }

    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
        successfulTasks++;
    }
}

// Handle last user  
if(curUser != null) {
    updateUser(user,group, successfulTasks); 
}
```

Is there a better (cleaner) way to do this? The above seems somewhat error-prone, especially that last user check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Pair` class which will have `User` and `Group` as final fields. Make sure `Pair` overrides `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Create a `HashMap<Pair,Integer>`, and maintain it [as a **histogram**] while iterating the list. [Need only one pass on the list for that].

Later, **iterate the histogram, and send an update for every `Pair`** [which is actually a tuple: `(User,Group)`] with the key - containing succesful runs.

Should look something like: [Pseudo-code, there might be some syntatic errors...]:

```
Map<Pair,Integer> histogram = new HashMap<Pair,Integer>();
for(Task task : tasksByGroupAndUser) {
   if (task.isSuccessful() == false) continue; //just skip unseccessful tasks.
   Pair current = new Pair(task.getUser(),task.getGroup());
   Integer value = histogram.get(current);
   histogram.put(current, value == null? 1 : value + 1); //update the histogram
}
for (Entry<Pair,Integer> entry : histogram.entrySet()) { 
   updateUser(entry.getKey().getUser(),entry.getKey().getGroup(),entry.getValue());
}
```

This solution is asymptotically faster then the suggested solution since it is not requires sorting - so the total runtime is `O(n)`. [while the algorithm suggested in the question is `O(nlogn)`].

Also: I find this solution easier to understand, but that might be a matter of opinion...

Comment: Thanks, I was going in this direction too but your code is better. Speed is less of a concern here but I also think this solution is cleaner and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the User object should have a List of tasks. The Task object should only have the id, purpose and isSuccessfull.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really change the class design

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, there is a class in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) called [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) that is excellent for this scenario. It counts the number of times an element has been entered into the set. So, based on amit's answer:

```
Multiset<Pair> histogram = new HashMultiset<Pair>(); // Pair is a tuple of (User,Group)
for(Task task : tasksByGroupAndUser) {
   if (task.isSuccessful()) {
      Pair current = new Pair(task.getUser(),task.getGroup());
      histogram.add(current);
   }
}
for (Pair pair : histogram) { 
   updateUser(pair.getUser(),pair.getGroup(),histogram.count(entry));
}
```